# how can I add a copy of a div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clone

I have a div containg a few dynamically generated dropdowns.

I want to clone this and add it underneath the original. The code for the original is:

```
<div id="subjectselectiondiv" style="width:inherit;">
    <h4>Select the subjects that you are able to tutor</h4>
    <div id='choices'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var doc = document.getElementById("choices");
            var subj_div = document.createElement('div');
            subj_div.setAttribute('class', 'selectSearchBar');
            subj_div.innerHTML = '<select id="level'+counter+'" name="level'+counter+'" class="selectSearchBar"><?php echo "<option>Level</option>"; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_level, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['level']."</option>";}?></select><div id="subject'+counter+'" style="display:inline;">sBar2</div><div id="topic'+counter+'" style="display:inline;">sbar3</div>';
            doc.appendChild(subj_div);
        </script>
    <a href='#' class="more" onclick="Repeat()">Add another subject</a>
</div>
```

I thought that the function Repeat() would work with:

```
function Repeat(){
    counter++;
    $('#choices').clone().appendTo('#subjectselectdiv');
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

but this isnt working - am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: just one question, why?

Comment: @Spokey thought that would be for the onclick that calls Repeat() since its a href="#"?

Comment: @SpYk3HH need to allow user to add other levels/subject/topics to their accounts - so they need to the ability to add more - though now I think about it I will have multiple divs with the same id which will cause me problems on form posts! will take another look at this

Comment: When cloning an element with an `id`, you should change it, otherwise it's duplicated and you'll have unexpected results

Comment: You also shouldnt have to write your script that way. Why not make you base select boxes with any base options you want included, then use the "add" button/function to update said select boxes as necessary. At that point, the only php should be an url of an ajax request for the data you want to use to add more options.

Comment: @SpYk3HH The user will need to select a level and subject for each entry and so its little use to have base options

Comment: @Ian - is there any way I can increment id from within Repeat() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name mismatches:

```
<div id="subjectselectiondiv" style="width:inherit;">
                     ^^^^^^
$('#choices').clone().appendTo('#subjectselectdiv');
                                            ^^^
```

What you're attempting to append to doesn't exist. Most likely if you'd bothered checking your javascript console, you'd have seen the warnings/errors about the non-existing element.